# React component doesn't update DOM

Tags: reactjs

CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-chandrasekhar-3jpw4

I am working on a battleship game application. In this game the user can click onto the opponents grid and select cells to attack. If a cell is attacked and it contains an enemy ship then it should have a class applied to it and consequently turn red.

I am having an issue where all of the functionality is working, but the component does not update when a move is made. If I go into my component's code to make a small change and then save it, I can see that the selected cell turns red (if it contains an enemy ship).

The GameboardSetup component generates the initial grids:

```
const createUiGrid = () => {
        const cells = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
          cells.push(i);
        }
        let counter = -1;
        const result = cells.map((cell) => {
          counter++;
          return (
            <div
              className="cell"
              id={counter}
              onClick={onClickHandler}
              onMouseOut={onMouseOutHandler}
              onMouseOver={onMouseOverHandler}
            />
          );
        });
        return result;
    };

    const generateAiGrid = () => {
        let aiPlacedShips = 0;
        let currentShipLength = null;
        let currentShipDirection = null;

        const generateShipDirection = () => {
            let randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
            if (randomNumber === 0) {
                return 'horizontal'
            }
            return 'vertical'
        }

        while (aiPlacedShips <= 4) {
            let unavailableCells = [];
            currentShipDirection = generateShipDirection();

            if (aiPlacedShips === 0) {
                currentShipLength = 5;
            } else {
                currentShipLength = ships[aiPlacedShips].length;
                for (let i = 0; i < aiGameboard.shipYard.length; i++) {
                    aiGameboard.shipYard[i].position.forEach((val) => {
                        unavailableCells.push(val);
                    })
                };
            };

            const generateRandom = (min, max) => {
                const num = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
                return (unavailableCells.includes(num)) ? generateRandom(min, max) : num;
            }
            
            let currentShipStartCell = generateRandom(0, 99);
            let currentShipEndCell = null;
            
            if (currentShipDirection === 'horizontal') {
                currentShipEndCell = currentShipStartCell + currentShipLength - 1;
            } else {
                currentShipEndCell = currentShipStartCell + ((currentShipLength - 1) * 10);
            };
    
            if ((aiGameboard.checkValidCoordinates(currentShipDirection, currentShipStartCell, currentShipEndCell)) && (!aiGameboard.checkIfShipPresent(currentShipDirection, currentShipStartCell, currentShipEndCell))) {
                aiGameboard.placeShip(aiPlacedShips, currentShipDirection, currentShipStartCell, currentShipEndCell);
                aiPlacedShips++;
            };
        };
    };
```

These are then passed up to the App component and stored in state via the below useEffect function:

```
useEffect(() => {
        if (placedShips >= 5){
            props.handleNextStepChange();
            props.setPlayerSetupGameboard(playerGameboard);
            props.setAiSetupGameboard(aiGameboard);
        }
    }, [placedShips]);
```

These grids are then passed down to the Game component via props:

```
    const showNextComponent = () => {
        if (phase === 1) {
            return (
                <GameboardSetup 
                    setPlayerSetupGameboard={setPlayerSetupGameboard}
                    setAiSetupGameboard={setAiSetupGameboard}
                    handleNextStepChange={handleNextStepChange}
                />
            );
        } else if (phase === 2) {
            return (
                <Game 
                    playerSetupGameboard={playerSetupGameboard}
                    aiSetupGameboard={aiSetupGameboard}
                />
            );
        } else {
            return (
                <Intro
                    setPlayerName={setPlayerName}
                    handleNextStepChange={handleNextStepChange}
                />
            );
        };
    };
```

The grids are then stored into state within the Game component:

```
    useEffect(() => {
        setPlayerGameboard(props.playerSetupGameboard);
        setAiGameboard(props.aiSetupGameboard);
    }, [props]);
```

The grids are then generated within the Game component:

```
const createPlayerGrid = (playerGameboard) => {

        if (!!playerGameboard) {

            let ships = [];
            let hitShips = [];

            for (let i = 0; i < playerGameboard.shipYard.length; i++) {
                playerGameboard.shipYard[i].position.forEach((cell) => {
                    ships.push(cell);
                });
            };

            for (let i = 0; i < playerGameboard.shipYard.length; i++) {
                playerGameboard.shipYard[i].hits.forEach((cell) => {
                    hitShips.push(cell);
                });
            };

            const cells = [];
            for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                cells.push(i);
            }
            let counter = -1;
            const result = cells.map((cell) => {
                let shipStatus = '';
                counter++;
                if (ships.includes(counter)) {
                    shipStatus = 'ship';
                }
                if (hitShips.includes(counter)) {
                    shipStatus = 'hit-ship';
                }
                return (
                    <div
                        className={`player-cell ${shipStatus}`}
                        id={counter}
                    />
                );
            });
            return result;  
        }
    };

    const createAiGrid = (aiGameboard) => {

        if (!!aiGameboard) {

            let ships = [];
            let hitShips = [];

            for (let i = 0; i < aiGameboard.shipYard.length; i++) {
                aiGameboard.shipYard[i].position.forEach((cell) => {
                    ships.push(cell);
                })
            }
            for (let i = 0; i < aiGameboard.shipYard.length; i++) {
                aiGameboard.shipYard[i].hits.forEach((cell) => {
                    hitShips.push(cell);
                });
            };

            const cells = [];
            for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                cells.push(i);
            }
            let counter = -1;
            const result = cells.map((cell) => {
                let shipStatus = '';
                counter++;
                if (ships.includes(counter)) {
                    shipStatus = 'ship';
                }
                if (hitShips.includes(counter)) {
                    shipStatus = 'hit-ship';
                }
                return (
                    <div
                        className={`ai-cell ${shipStatus}`}
                        id={counter}
                        onClick={onClickHandler}
                    />
                );
            });
            return result;  
        }
    };
```

The results from these functions are then rendered within the return function:

```
    return (
        <div className="main-container">
            <div className="player-container">
                <div className="player-grid">
                    <Table grid={createPlayerGrid(playerGameboard)} />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="ai-container">
                <div className="ai-grid">
                    <Table grid={createAiGrid(aiGameboard)} />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
```

As I mentioned above, if I make an amendment to the Game component and save it after making a valid hit move, the hit-ship class is appended to that cell and it becomes red.

I'm not sure why this is happening, but am relatively new to React and would be very grateful for any suggestions.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The onClickHandler was only firing a single time and is now functioning with the below:

```
    const onClickHandler = (e) => {
        if (turn === true) {
            console.log(aiGameboard)
            humanPlayer.attack(aiGameboard, e.target.id);
        };
        console.log(aiGameboard)
        humanPlayer.attack(aiGameboard, e.target.id);   // TEMPORARY
        toggleTurn();
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all i wouldnt be using the same state twice and keep them in sync with the useEffect function.
I recommend using React context as follows
Create Context.Provider and pass values. (Maybe even the setValue function)
Inside every component dont pass those shared state via props. Instead make use of React.useContext() Function
Check out: https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html